# Get ARIMA white noise with known parameter in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a `MA(1)` model with known parameter [image: formula] and known [image: formula].

[image: formula]

I'd like to know, is there a function in `R` that can return [image: formula] for me?

I also tried to get  [image: formula] by iteration:

[image: formula]

However, in reality, [image: formula]  is unknown and [image: formula] cannot be specified at the first place.

I'm having this question because I used `gnls` to estimate a nonlinear model with residuals being `MA(1)` process. The code is something like:

```
model = gnls(y ~ c + log( x1^g + x2^g), start = list(c = 0.04, g = 0.3),
      correlation = corARMA(c(0.5), form = ~ 1, p = 0, q = 1, fixed = FALSE))
```

It returns every parameter estimation including [image: formula]. But `residuals(model)` returns [image: formula] instead of [image: formula].

So any suggestions?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Arima function available in R.

```
fit <- arima(ts(data), order=c(0,0,1))
```

as you do not want AR and I part. You can set it to zero.

```
summary(fit)
```

You can observe parameters learned and errors by summary function.

For more information, refer to : https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But the thing is I know the value of `theta` --- it was got from another regression model. I have the raw residuals and `theta`, what I want is the so-called "white noise".